# Button hit testing performance spikes?

Tags: flash, adobe-scout

I only have one button, so when I run Scout on my test build and I roll over the button, button hit testing spikes crazy. What could be the cause of this? Also I'm curious about the 11 x Mouse handle events.

Here is my profiler in action:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/amPGk.png

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the flash button is just a load of crap so I switched from using their button class to my own class with custom mouse skins, also I found out flash doesn't run well on the standalone player which is another shocker. You'd think the standalone would work better than the browser version.